# next available record id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

```
@user = User.new
```

`@user.id` returns nil but i need to know it before i save. Is it possible ?

Comment: I'd take a look at the following answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466908/get-id-of-rails-model-before-saving before going down that route.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Possibly you are approaching something the wrong way, e.g. building relationships...

Comment: `User.maximum(:id).next` [http://stackoverflow.com/a/17523916/2231236]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't get the ID before saving. The ID number comes from the database but the database won't assign the ID until you call `save`. All this is assuming that you're using ActiveRecord of course.

Answer (score 13):

YES you can!

I had the same question and investigated the docs.
The ability to solve this question is very related to your database type in fact.

**Oracle** and **Postgresql** do have useful functions to easily solve this.
For MySQL(oracle) or **SkySQL**(open-source) it seems more complicated (but still possible). I would recommend you avoid using these (MySQL/SkySQL) databases if you need advanced database tools.

First you must **try to avoid this situation as much as possible in your application design**, as it is dangerous to play with IDs before they get saved.

There may be situation where you don't have any other choice:
For instance when two tables are referencing themselves and for security reason you don't allow DELETE or UPDATE on these tables.

When this is the case, you can use the (PostgreSQL, Oracle) database ***nextval*** function to generate the next ID number without actually inserting a new record.

Use it in conjunction with the **find_by_sql** rails method.

To do this with postgreSQL and Rails for instance, choose one of your rails models and add a class method (not an instance method!).
This is possible with the "**self**" word at the beginning of the method name.
**self** tells Ruby that this method is usable only by the class, not by its instance variables (the objects created with 'new').

My Rails model:

```
class MyToy < ActiveRecord::Base

...

  def self.my_next_id_sequence
    self.find_by_sql "SELECT nextval('my_toys_id_seq') AS my_next_id"
  end
end
```

When you generate a table with a Rails migration, by default Rails automatically creates a column called **id** and sets it as the **primary key's table**. To ensure that you don't get any "*duplicate primary key error*", Rails automatically creates a **sequence** inside the database and applies it to the **id** column. For each new record (row) you insert in your table, the database will calculate by itself what will be the next id for your new record.

Rails names this sequence automatically with the **table name append with "_id_seq"**.
The PostgreSQL nextval function must be applied to this sequence as explained [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-sequence.html).

Now about **find_by_sql**, as explained [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql), it will create **an array** **containing new objects instances** of your class. Each of those objects will contain all the columns the SQL statement generates. Those columns will appear in each new object instance under the form of attributes. **Even if those attributes don't exist in your class model** !

As you wisely realized, our nextval function will only return a single value.
So find_by_sql will create **an array** containing a **single object instance with a single attribute**.
To make it easy to read the value of this very attribute, we will name the resulting SQL column with "my_next_id", so our attribute will have the same name.

So that's it. We can use our new method:

```
my_resulting_array = MyToy.my_next_id_sequence
my_toy_object = my_resulting_array[0]
my_next_id_value = my_toy_object.my_next_id
```

And use it to solve our dead lock situation :

```
my_dog = DogModel.create(:name => 'Dogy', :toy_id => my_next_id_value)

a_dog_toy = MyToy.new(:my_dog_id => my_dog.id)
a_dog_toy.id = my_next_id_value
a_dog_toy.save
```

**Be aware that** if you don't use your my_next_id_value this id number will be lost forever. (I mean, it won't be used by any record in the future).

The database doesn't wait on you to use it. If somewhere at any time, your application needs to insert a new record in your my_table_example (maybe at the same time as we are playing with my_next_id_sequence), the database will always assign an id number to this new record immediately following the one you generated with my_next_id_sequence, considering that your my_next_id_value is reserved.
This may lead to situations where the records in your my_table_example don't appear to be sorted by the time they were created.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar situation. I called the sequence using find_by_sql on my model which returns the model array. I got the id from the first object of the arry. something like below.

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        set_primary_key 'user_id'
        alias user_id= id=
    def self.get_sequence_id
        self.find_by_sql "select TEST_USER_ID_SEQ.nextval as contact_id from dual"
    end
end
```

and on the class on which you reference the user model,

```
@users = User.get_sequence_id
user = users[0]
```

Comment: If you're using Postgres `from dual` should be dropped as Postgres doesn't support that syntax, but it doesn't require a from in order to return the value either.  So the find by sql statement becomes `self.find_by_sql "select nextval(TEST_USER_ID_SEQ) as contact_id"`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the ID is filled from a database sequence automatically.

In rails you can use the `after_create` event, which gives you access to the object just after it has been saved (and thus it has the ID). This would cover most cases.

When using Oracle i had the case where I wanted to create the ID ourselves (and not use a sequence), and in [this post](http://www.dixis.com/?p=127) i provide the details how i did that. In short the code:

```
# a small patch as proposed by the author of OracleEnhancedAdapter: http://blog.rayapps.com/2008/05/13/activerecord-oracle-enhanced-adapter/#comment-240
# if a ActiveRecord model has a sequence with name "autogenerated", the id will not be filled in from any sequence
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedAdapter.class_eval do
  alias_method :orig_next_sequence_value, :next_sequence_value

  def next_sequence_value(sequence_name)
    if sequence_name == 'autogenerated'
      # we assume id must have gotten a good value before insert!
      id
    else
      orig_next_sequence_value(sequence_name)
    end
  end
end
```

while this solution is specific to Oracle-enhanced, i am assuming the other databases will have a similar method that you could redefine.

So, while it is definitely not advised and you want to be absolutely sure why you would not want to use an id generated by a sequence, if it is needed it is most definitely possible.
It is why I love ruby and Ruby on Rails! :)

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you can get your current sequence value with this query:

```
SELECT last_number FROM user_sequences where sequence_name='your_sequence_name';
```

So in your model class, you can put something like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.sequence_name = 'your_sequence_name'

  def self.my_next_id_sequence
    get_data = self.find_by_sql "SELECT last_number FROM user_sequences where sequence_name='your_sequence_name'"
    get_data[0].last_number
  end

end
```

And finally, in controller you can get this value with this:

```
my_sequence_number = MyModel.my_next_id_sequence
```

So, there is no need to get your next value by using NEXTVAL and you won't lose you ID.

Comment: This is very old, but also dangerous enough to warant a comment. Selecting the last number from user_sequences is _very_ wrong. Sure, it works on the surface, but it ignores all kinds of problems (like some other transaction grabbing an ID). Also, in this particular example you get the LAST id and the method is named NEXT_id... Bad idea! There is no way to get the next ID except to use `.nextval`, and yes, this will "use up" IDs, if you don't actually save them. But this cannot be circumvented.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is User.max(id). which will return the highest ID in the database, you could then add 1.  This is not reliable, although might meet your needs.

Comment: Not reliable in the slightest. Take an example using postgres - if someone fails to insert a record 3 times, and the transaction rolls back, the next value will be off by 3, better to do a database specific nextval('seq') or even better would be to not do this at all.

Comment: And you'd have a race condition: compute max, someone else does an insert, then you try your insert.

Answer (score 0):

Since Rails 5 you can simply call [`next_sequence_value`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb#L242)

Note: For Oracle when `self.sequence_name` is set, requesting next sequence value creates side effect by incrementing sequence value