# Is it possible to increment a postgresql entry even if it doesn't exist?

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, increment

As it says on the tin. I'm looking for something like Redis' `INCR`, except I also would like to then query for all the item where `count` is greater than 1.

I'm anticipating a 20-30 gigabytes of data, otherwise I'd just do it in-memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PostgreSQL's [Sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createsequence.html):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE serial START 1;

SELECT nextval('sequence_name');
```

Also, take a look at this second answer: [next available record id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456621/next-available-record-id)