# Friendly ID slug does not contain the id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I want to have urls like this:

```
http://domain.com/products/454-table-lamp
```

So I use friendly_id like so:

```
extend FriendlyId

friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :history

def slug_candidates
  [
      [:id, :title]
  ]
end
```

Now, since friendly id generates the slug before the object is saved I end up with an url like so (Please note the missing id in the URL):

```
http://domain.com/products/table-lamp
```

Now while this is not too bad as such. As soon as I save another Product called "Table Lamp", I will get an URL like this:

```
http://domain.com/products/table-lamp-ebaf4bf5-a6fb-4824-9a07-bdda34f56973
```

So my question is, how can I make sure, friendly ID creates the slug containing the ID as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add an after_commit callback to your model. In this callback, set slug to nil and save:

```
  after_commit :update_slug, on: :create

  def update_slug
    unless slug.include? self.id.to_s
      self.slug = nil
      self.save
    end
  end
```

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your answer, because I ran into a stack-overflow so I have to check that the id is not already there

Comment: Thank you Besi :). I guess `after_commit :update_slug, on: :create` do the trick for it. Is it mandatory to check the id ?

Comment: Yes when I don't check the id on every save, the `update_slug` method will be called again.

Comment: Even with the guard clause on: :create ? It should run it once

Comment: What do you mean by `guard clause`?

Comment: I'm not sure how it is called, but the "on: :create" should limit the range of action of the callback. It should be called only once due to this, that's why I don't understand why you want to check the id in the callback

Comment: I agree, but I ran into a stack overflow and adding the check fixed the problem.

Comment: Oooh I see. This is infinite loop, the callback keeps running all the time. because you save in the callback, it is wrapped in the transaction and recalls himself ! Fine ! Good job :)

Comment: Why not use `after_create` instead of `after_commit`, it avoids the infinite loop?

Comment: Just see my comment above. It will call update_slug infinitely. In an after _create callback, if you try to save your model it will trigger the same callback again

Comment: I'm trying to get this working but my logs show an error that seems to be looping infinitely. This is my code and the error https://gist.github.com/colmtuite/a2525bd98f79f285484cf3384c82ea39

Answer (score 2):

Well, the short answer - you can't. FrienlydId generates slug in `before_validation` callback here: https://git.io/vgn89. The problem is that you need to generate slug before saving to avoid conflicts, but you want to use information that available only after actual save, when record is already in db.

Take a look on this [answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466908/get-id-of-rails-model-before-saving).

Of course, you can do something like if you really want it:

```
def slug_candidates
  [ title, Model.maximum(:id) + 1 ]
end
```

But this code is not thread safe and can lead to some obvious problems. Another way - change the slug after save, in `after_create` callback for example. You can set it to `nil` and call `set_slug` again.

But ask yourself - do you really need it? May be it is better to use timestamp from created_at for example as a part of slug candidates?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I could do it with the help of both Terry and a `after_commit` callback. See his answer.

Comment: You are welcome =) Yep, it will work. But in this case you have double save on creation and you will not see any validation errors if something bad happens during the save in after_commit.