# Redirect parameterized URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the record's ID and name in the URL.

```
def to_param
    "#{id} #{name}".parameterize
end
```

But any name works in the URL. I can do the following and it works

```
www.site.com/records/ID-anything-here-works
```

How can I redirect `ID-anything` to `ID-name`?

Here is an example.

Let's say I have a "product" model and a record with the name "shoe" and an id "6".

The url looks like this

```
products/6-shoe
```

But this URL also works

```
products/6-eiufwojfeowjfowef
```

How can I make it so the second URL redirects to the first?

I'm working with the show action:

```
def show
    @website = Website.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. can you please rephrase it?

Comment: Ok i think i understand what you mean: you want them to only enter a name which is current available in the database?

Comment: The record name and record ID are in the database. I want the ID and name to be in the URL and I have this working currently. But the record seems to be retrieved by the ID only, I can type in anything I want for the name in the URL and it displays the record. I want it to redirect to ID-name.

Comment: have you overriden with to_param in your model?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "overridden" - maybe I have, maybe I haven't, I'm not sure. But in the question, I showed the def_param snippet I have in my model.

Comment: ok i'll provide an implementation below just gimme a couple of minutes.

Comment: I updated my question with an example, hopefully that is a bit clearer?

Comment: yup perfectly clear. I don't have the details of what exactly you want, so I couldn't be more specific, but this should give you a general idea of what to do. In fact look at it in 10 minutes because i'm going to refresh the answer

Comment: sorry bro i changed my answer a couple of times because i kept making spelling mistakes. hope this helps

Comment: Just a suggestion: have you checked [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)? It handles very nicely friendly urls, so you don't have to write from scratch.

Comment: I'm using friendly-id gem, but I need this model to be unique, so I figured I have to include the ID in the url? So I used this method of parameterizing the record name and including it alongside the ID, but I can't get it working. Does FriendlyID handle this need? I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: no - authentication - that's not the problem. The problem is that when rails redirect_to in the URL it redirects to website/id      WITHOUT the name in the URL. so then it is looping infinitely. we want to override the show_website_path helper method so that it it includes the Name in the URL as well.

Comment: Yeah, rake routes shows the website url as  /w/:id. Is there a way to force that to be /w/:id-:name?

Comment: I think you'll have to override the show_website route helper method so it will redirect to  /w/:id-:name. bro i'm gonna have to throw in the towel. i gave it a good shot.

Comment: Noooooooo you can't leave me!! Ha, thanks man, appreciate all the help!

Comment: @colmtuite yes, friendly_id will allways generate a unique slug, you just set the candidates. When it generates a slug, it tries the first one. If exists, try  the second one. And so on. If all of them are repeated, it appends a random hash. You specify this keys with a `slug_candidates` method. But putting `id` in a slug when using friendly_id is not a good idea because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35221321/3889043) (you don't have the auto generated id yet when the slug is generated)

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks for the link, I'll go with the after_create update_slug thing.

Comment: @colmtuite how was this different to what we were trying hahah nice one mate :)

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Well the other solution uses FriendlyID and actually adds the ID into the slug. I couldn't get it working though and also though there might be issues when the slug is updated. So I went with Dmitry's solution below which is similar to the one you suggested. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  def show
    @website = Website.find(params[:id])
    unless params[:id] == @website.to_param
      redirect_to @website, status: 301
    end
  end
```

It finds the instance as it is doing now (negligent of the name), but then it redirects a user to a correct path with current name.

Note the 301 status in redirect, this is good for SEO, you will have only one actual URL for each website.