# Rails - automatically populate a field based on id, on creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to automatically populate a field which is based on `MyModel.id`. What's the correct `before_x`-like filter to use? the private method that I use is like:

```
def _generate_code
  hashids = Hashids.new("this is my salt", 6)
  self.code = 'WA' + hashids.encode(self.id).upcase
end
```

I also need to secure `validates_presence_of :code` and `validates_uniqueness_of :code`

the problem is that in `before_save` the Model.id is not present, and I can't reach `after_save` since it fails validations

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22684610/3609100

Comment: I put `next_id=Wallet.connection.select_value("Select nextval('wallets_id_seq')")` in my _generate_code method but it keeps failing validations

Comment: Code uniq fails? Did you remember to use 'next_id' in _generate_code instead of self.id (which is probably null always, at the moment when it's called)?

Comment: yes, I actually made it working using a `before_validation` filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is working when called in a `before_validation` filter

```
def _generate_code
  if !self.code
    next_id=Wallet.connection.select_value("Select nextval('wallets_id_seq')")
    hashids = Hashids.new("this is my salt", 6)
    self.code = 'WA' + hashids.encode(next_id).upcase
  end
end
```